# Can I send emails without authenticating on the SMTP server?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am creating simple email sending application. In my application when ever I send email I have to put my email address or password as from but I don't want to use password only want to put email.

So:

Can I send email without using password using C#/.net application?

This is my code:

```
try
{
    // setup mail message
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox2.Text));
    message.Subject = textBox3.Text;
    message.Body = richTextBox1.Text;

    // setup mail client
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text,"password");

    // send message
    mailClient.Send(message);

    MessageBox.Show("Sent");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

Comment: You can't Authenticate with wrong credentials. In another words if you have password (and gmail requires one) you can't log in without sending your password so you won't be able to send anything.

Comment: Why not just save the Authentication details after the first login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i send Email without using password using c#/.net application ?

Yes, if you have access to an email gateway that doesn't require authentication you can simply do:

```
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("your.emailgateway.com");
mailClient.Send(message);
```

Maybe your company or ISP can provide one for you?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can, sure. In your concrete example code you are using Gmail which does not allow anonymous sending.

From [their references](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en):

> smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
> Use Authentication: Yes
> Port for
> TLS/STARTTLS: 587
> Port for SSL: 465

An additional comment regarding your `catch` clause:

In my opinion you are heavily misusing the exception idea. A better approach would be something like:

```
catch(Exception x)
{
    var s = x.Message;
    if ( x.InnerException!=null )
    {
        s += Environment.NewLine + x.InnerException.Message;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```