# Best way to do MVC email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Basically what I'm trying to do is send an email from an MVC website without having to do something not secure store email credentials of a Gmail account for example.The emails will just be from a contact page to the webmasters email account, what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always set the credentials for the account within the web.config of the site and then use ASPNET_REGIIS to encrypt the data. Your application will still be able to read this but if anyone were able to access your web.config they would not be able to make anything from the data.

This way you can just use the standard smtp classes in .net

Here is an example of doing this for a database connection string for example.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStri
ngs" C:\inetpub\wwwroot -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

Answer (score -1):

To send an email without authentication you can setup your own `smtp` server; check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490956/2591693) question. Alternatively you can:

1. Setup a `gmail` account specifically for this contact form and employ one of the methods from the other answers
2. Save contact form submissions to your database and access them directly or through an admin site