# How to include gridview values as attachment while sending mail

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments

I would like to add the file name from 2 nd column [`DRAFT PATH`] and include as attachment while sending mail.
How can i add this details as an attachment and i need to include text information in my body.

for Ex;-
In the given link https://imageshack.com/i/f0YGXzlvj you can see there is only one file in `Draft path`. So i need to attach that file from the folder.. as an attachment..
Also i need to include

[Body of mail]

```
     Total number of files :    Draft path files
     File1:- file name of `draft path` file
```

As you can see the  rest cells are empty.. so no need to mention in Body..

**If more files is there then i need to do according to that..**

Code snippet:-

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sending Mail. Click Ok!!!", "Mail!!!.");
        string smtpserver = ini.ReadValue("bmail", "smtpserver");
        string email_From = ini.ReadValue("bmail", "email_From");
        string email_Recipient = ini.ReadValue("bmail", "email_Recipient");
        string email_Subject = ini.ReadValue("bmail", "email_Subject");
        string email_Body = ini.ReadValue("bmail", "email_Body");


            try
            {
                new SmtpClient(smtpserver, 25).Send(email_From,
                                      email_Recipient,
                                      email_Subject,
                                      email_Body);
                MessageBox.Show("Email Successfully Sent!!!", "Mail!!!.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

How can i do this..
Please help me out.

Comment: what is the problem, adding the attachment or retrieving the file from the path ?

Comment: @mybirthname i cannot add attachment and don't know how to include file name to the body of the mail.

Comment: @mybirthname any idea!!!!!

Comment: Please guys.. anyone out here... to help me out!!!

Comment: here check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send mail like this with attachement.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("stacy@gmail.com", "Stacy Kebler");
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 465;  //set the default smtp port of email provider. you can avoid it if you don't know
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("stacy@gmail.com", "stacy123");
smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Set this to true if the email provider is using SSL encryption 
smtp.Timeout = 10000; //Set the timeout to 10 second

msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com","Mr. ABC"));
msg.IsBodyHtml = true; //if the content of body is in HTML format then set it to true.


msg.Subject = "This is a sample message";

StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
sbBody.Append("This is the Sample Email <br><br>");
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["DRAFT_PATH"].Value != null && 
        System.IO.File.Exists(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["DRAFT_PATH"].Value.ToString()))
    {
        string path = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["DRAFT_PATH"].Value.ToString();
        sbBody.AppendFormat("File {0}:{1}<br>", i + 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
    }
}
msg.Body = sbBody.ToString();


smtp.Send(msg);
```

---

if you don't want to block the current thread while email is sending. then you can use asynchronous method to send the mail. That will not block the process during the email sending. You just need to use `SendAsync()` method instead of `Send()`

```
smtp.SendAsync(msg, "Test Message");
```

Where the second parameter is for token of that process. If you want to do any further process after sending email and you are also sending multiple emails then `token` will help you to determine specific mail process.

for example: if you are sending two mails at the same time

```
smtp1.SendAsync(msg1, "Test Message 1");
smtp1.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(this.SendCompletedCallback);


smtp2.SendAsync(msg2, "Test Message 2");
smtp2.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(this.SendCompletedCallback);


private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
    String token = (string) e.UserState;

    if (token == "Test Message 1")
        //This is the First email status
    else if (token == "Test Message 2")
        //This is the second email status
}
```

---

if you want to send email without assigning credential then you must have a email gateway of email server.

```
SmtpClient msg = new SmtpClient("username.gateway.com");
```

Comment: attachment is coming in a perfect way.. but the thing is i don't need the line `smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("stacy@gmail.com", "stacy123");
` i mean with out credentials.. how can i do this. please see my question.. i need something like that.. because i don't want to give credentials. Also i want to give in the body of mail.. with the file name.. like line by line..

Comment: for example.. File1 :- 224-3323_01. File2 :- 121-2322_00.. like this.. i want to extract the filenames and put in the body.. also...

Comment: without userid and password you cannot send the email otherwise i can also send the fake email from your account. It is not possible. And I am also updating my answer.

Comment: Is this your private mail server?

Comment: Yes... its my company mail server

Comment: previously i use to give to give a fake from_email address and to address will be genuine .. and i use company SMTp server..

Comment: To send the email without credential you must have a email gateway. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12490956/3761928

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62151/discussion-between-stacy-kebler-and-shell).

Comment: i have emailed the check box column.. full project to ur id.. please have a look and reply me back!!!

Comment: i does not exist in the body... `sbBody.AppendFormat("File {0}:{1}<br>", i + 1, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strPath));`

Comment: I have included my body also.. but the newline is not coming.. `sbBody.AppendFormat(email_Body,"<br><br>");`.. The new line is not coming

Comment: have u set the `msg.IsBodyHtml = true;`. Show me your code in pastie.